# Creating new JSON by reading distinct JSON array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON object that looks something like this

OBJECT $deals

```
[
  {
    "deal_id": 124563
    "merchant_id": 123
    "merchant_name": Merchant1
  }
  {
    "deal_id": 456789
    "merchant_id": 123
    "merchant_name": Merchant1
  }
  {
    "deal_id": 46646
    "merchant_id": 456
    "merchant_name": Merchant2
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is this right now

```
$category_merchants = array();
foreach ($deals as $deal) {
  array_push($category_merchants, $deal->merchant_id, $deal->merchant_name)
}
$category_merchants = json_encode($category_merchants);
```

The new JSON object has all the merchants from the original JSON. Is there an easy way to just get the distinct merchants (merchant_name, merchant_id) in the new JSON with counts of how many times they were in the original JSON?

Comment: Did you give up on this or what?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I was able to resolve this today. Luckily I am using Laravel as a framework and it has something known as collections. I can use collections to get distinct with a built in function.

Answer (score 0):

use array_map() like this:

```
array_map(function($v){return [$v->merchant_id, $v->merchant_name];}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert json to array

   `$array = json_decode($deals);`
2. loop array to get unique merchant name

   `foreach($array as $key => $value) {
       $category_merchants[$value['merchant_id']] = $value['merchant_name'];
       $category_merchant_count[] = $value['merchant_id']; //this is to count number of merchant occurance
   }`
3. Convert category_merchants back to json

   `$merchant = json_encode($category_merchants);`
4. Get number of merchant occurance

   `print_r(array_count_values($category_merchant_count))`

Answer (score 0):

One way.  Just use the `merchant_id` as the key and increment the count:

```
$deals = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($deals as $deal) {
  if(!isset($category_merchants[$deal['merchant_id']])) {
      $category_merchants[$deal['merchant_id']] = $deal;
      $category_merchants[$deal['merchant_id']]['count'] = 1;
      unset($category_merchants[$deal['merchant_id']]['deal_id']);
  } else {
      $category_merchants[$deal['merchant_id']]['count']++;
  }      
}
```

If you need to re-index the array then:

```
$category_merchants = array_values($category_merchants);
```